# Azure Synapse write ADLS file with list of file names

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

I am trying to use Azure Synapse **Get Metadata** activity to get list of files present in ADLSv2 and the use Lookup activity with following SQL to get just files names

```
declare @output varchar(max)
set @output ='@{activity('Get Metadata').output.childitems}'
select concat('[',string_agg(name,','),']')  as name from OpenJson(@output) with(name varchar(max) '$.name')
```

After this I want to store the list into a file using Copy Activity. I have following in **Copy** activity

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run this I get following error

```
"ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'"
```

What I am missing here ?

I want to have test file `filename_list.txt` created with list of files present in ADLS directory

```
details_01_01_2021.json
details_02_01_2021.json
details_03_01_2021.json
details_04_01_2021.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Error:

```
"ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidValueInPayload,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Failed to convert the value in 'value' property to 'System.String' type. Please make sure the payload structure and value are correct.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.DataContracts,''Type=System.InvalidCastException,Message=Object must implement IConvertible.,Source=mscorlib,'"
```

The error is occurring because `@activity('lookup').output.value` gives the value in array of json format. And it is not able to convert into String.

In additional column you can you the below expression.

```
@replace(replace(replace(replace(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].name,',','
    '),'"',''),']',''),'[','')
```

- `activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].name`: This gets the value of the 'name' property from the first element (index 0) of the output array of a Lookup activity named 'Lookup1'. This assumes that the Lookup activity is configured to return an array of objects and that each object has a 'name' property.
- `replace(..., ',', '\n')`: Replaces commas (,) with newline characters (\n).
  This is to format the string by replacing commas with line breaks.
- `replace(..., '"', '')`: Replaces double quotation marks (") with an empty string. This is used to remove double quotes from the string.
- `replace(..., ']', '')`: Replaces closing square brackets (]) with an
  empty string. This is used to remove closing square brackets from the string.
- `replace(..., '[', '')`: Replaces opening square brackets ([) with an empty string. This is used to remove opening square brackets from the string.

**Result:**
[image]